# Geodesic approximation and Euclidean continuation

Tags: ads-cft, wick-rotation

I recently read many articles in the context of the AdS/CFT correspondance in which the geodesic approximation is used (see for example section 3.5 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0622)).
The correlator between two boundary operators with scaling index of $\Delta$ and the geodesic length $d$ of a bulk field of mass $m$, with $\Delta=\frac{d}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{d}{2}+m^2}$ (the radius of AdS is one), is given by
$$
<O(x)O(y)> \sim e^{- m d(x,y)}
$$
for $m \gg 1$. $d(x,y)$ represents the geodesic distance between points $x$ and $y$.

I have no problem with this, what I didn't understand is why this is true only for geometries which can be analytically continued to Euclidean signature. Why is this, or more generically, where is my geodesic approximation coming from?